# Get user comments and all comments grouped within the same query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently working with Rails 5 and Postgresql. There's a model Post that can have many comments, through a model called PostComments, that way a comment can belong to a single post, but that post can have many comments. I'm trying to get all comments, grouped in the ones belonging to a specific user, and all other that not.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_comments
  has_many :comments, through: :post_comments
  ...

class Coment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_comments
  has_many :posts, through: :post_comments
  ...
```

Currently I'm doing two queries and comparing, like:

```
foo = Comment.select(:id, :description)
bar = Comment.joins(:post).select(:id, :description).where(posts: { id: post_id })
remaining_comments = [foo - bar, foo]
```

This gives me all comments for a specific store, and all the remaining ones, but I was wondering is there a better way on doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the comments in one query like below:

```
@comments = Comment.left_outer_joins(:post)
                   .select("comments.id,comments.description,posts.id as post_id")
                   .where("posts.id = ? OR posts.id IS NULL",  post_id })
```

Then split using `group_by`:

```
remaining_comments = @comments.group_by(&:post_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you group the query result?, really in my case Comment doesn't have a post_id attribute, since PostComment is which contains both foreign keys.

Comment: @PhilipDortmund I know, **post_id** is a virtual field I have created from `posts.id` in the query so I can use it later for grouping. I can see in your question that you have used `posts.id` as a FK.

Comment: Sorry, didn't got that. This works - there's an extra `}` in the code :).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting you correctly, you're trying to efficiently get an array of PostComments that do not belong to a particular Post?

If this is the case, simply use the `not` method:

```
x = # given Post id
post = Post.find(x).id
postcomments = PostComment.where.not(post_id: post)
```

Comment: This is an approach, but involves two queries, plus another one to get the post comments that do belong to the specific post. Also `Post.find(x).id` makes a `SELECT  "posts".* FROM ...` query.